# Download from FTP and Copy it into the Azure Blob/Amazon S3 directly without storing it in local system in Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, ftp

I want to download a file from FTP and upload it to Azure blob using Node.js. I am using `basic-ftp` NPM to list and download the file from FTP.

Can anyone provide a small example of how to upload the file into Amazon S3/Azure Blob storage without storing it into the local system?

Comment: Any process now, is this what you want? Or did you still have other problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the below code, I download a ftp file `test.txt` and upload the stream to blob, this could work for me.

```
var Client = require('ftp');
var fs = require('fs');

var azure = require('azure-storage');
accountName="account name"
accountKey="account key"
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName,accountKey);
let connection={
    "host":"ftp host",
    "port":"21",
    "user":"user name",
    "password":"pass word"
}
var c=new Client();


c.on('ready', function() {
    c.get('test.txt', function(err, stream) {
      if (err) throw err;

      stream.once('close', function() { c.end(); });
      stream.pipe(blobService.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob("test","test.txt"))

    });
  });
  c.connect(connection);
```